# Svelte component not forwarding an event

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-component

I have a series of 3 Svelte components, one inside the other, and am trying to forward an event from the innermost to the outermost component. However, the event is only triggered on the second, middle component, and is never triggered on the outermost.

Innermost (`TreeNodeView.svelte`)

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";
  import TreeNode from "./TreeNode";
  import TreeView from "./TreeView.svelte";

  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

  function onWantsUpload() {
    console.log("TreeNodeView");
    dispatch("wantsUpload", treeNode.id);
  }

  export let treeNode: TreeNode;
</script>

<li>
  </span>
    <span class="upload"
          aria-label={`Upload new version: ${treeNode.text}`}
          role="button"
          on:click={onWantsUpload}
          on:keyup={onWantsUpload}>
      <Upload title={`Upload new version: ${treeNode.text}`} />
    </span>
</li>
```

Middle (`TreeView.svelte`)

```
<script lang="ts">
  import TreeNode from "./TreeNode";
  import TreeNodeView from "./TreeNodeView.svelte";

  export let treeNodes: Array<TreeNode>;
</script>

<ul role="group">
    {#each treeNodes as treeNode ( treeNode.id )}
        <TreeNodeView
          {treeNode}
          on:wantsUpload />
    {/each}
</ul>
```

Outermost (`ProjectDetail.svelte`)

```
<script lang="ts">
  import ProjectDetailModel from "../../../models/ProjectDetail";
  import TreeNode from "../treeView/TreeNode";
  import TreeView from "../treeView/TreeView.svelte";

  export let treeNodes: Array<TreeNode>;
  export let projectDetail: ProjectDetailModel;

  function onWantsUpload(e: CustomEvent<string>) {
    console.log("ProjectDetail");
  }
</script>

<TreeView
  {treeNodes}
  on:wantsUpload={onWantsUpload} />
```

When I click the *Upload* element on the innermost component, I expect in the console to see ...

> TreeNodeView
> ProjectDetail

... but all I see is ...

> TreeNodeView

To debug, I've modified the middle component (`TreeView.svelte`) to explicitly handle and then re-dispatch the event:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { createEventDispatcher } from "svelte";
  import TreeNode from "./TreeNode";
  import TreeNodeView from "./TreeNodeView.svelte";

  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();

  export let treeNodes: Array<TreeNode>;

  function onWantsUpload(e: CustomEvent<string>) {
    console.log("TreeView");
    dispatch("wantsUpload", e.detail);
  }
</script>

<ul role="group">
    {#each treeNodes as treeNode ( treeNode.id )}
        <TreeNodeView
          {treeNode}
          on:wantsUpload={onWantsUpload} />
    {/each}
</ul>
```

And now, when I click the *Upload* element on the innermost component, I expect in the console to see ...

> TreeNodeView
> TreeView
> ProjectDetail

... but all I see is ...

> TreeNodeView
> TreeView

What have I missed? Why is my outermost component not receiving the event, or why is the middle component not dispatching the event?

Comment: It does seem to work https://svelte.dev/repl/cd3eb4de16ba443fb8cb971cf5b5ba23?version=4.2.10

Comment: So what can get in the way? What can prevent this happening in my components? The only difference between your reproduction and my application is styling and some additional markup. So